# Get appname in jndi lookup when jboss 7 server starts

Tags: spring, jboss, jndi

I have a problem with jboss 7 config on a spring project. When the server starts some ejbs should initialize in a context xml file, and everything work fine if i do like below.

bean property name="jndi" value="java:global/APP-NAME/MODULE-NAME!Classpath"

but i dont want to specify the appname because i have multiple instances of the application and they have different names. I have tested to use java:app, java:module but i need to go with java:global due to access. The modulename is no probelm, it is same on all instances.

My app is deployed in a war file and needs the appname when i do jndi lookup.

Is there a way to get the appname?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. In spring context im using my own LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean and override setJndiName method and get the module name from initialContext.lookup("java:module/ModuleName") and set the jndi name.
Everything works fine.